# Generating all unique combination from Dictionary<int, List<T>>

Tags: c#

I have the following dictionary :
`Dictionary<int, List<myObject>>`

I would like to get all the combination possibles of myObject and taking only one myObject instance per key. The number of key and number of myObject per key will change.

So as an example, if I have the following dictionary:

```
{
  { 0, {A1, A2},
  { 1, {B1},
  { 2, {C1, C2},
}
```

I would like to have:

{A1, B1, C1}, {A1, B1, C2}, {A2, B1, C1}, {A2, B1, C2}

It's easy to do this with nested foreach, if the number of list is the always the same but when it's changing, I can't find an easy way of doing this.

Any Idea how to do this?

**Edit:**
The dictionary is not used for anything else.

The harcoded nested foreach approach would be (pseudo code):

```
var result = new List<List<myObject>>
foreach myObjectA in myListForKey(0)
   foreach myObjectB in myListForKey(1)
       foreach myObjectC in myListForKey(2)
           result.add(new list<myObject>{myObjectA , myObjectB, myObjectC  })
```

The problem of this approach is that here I can handle scenario for only 3 keys, it's not dynamic, if there are more keys that that in the dictionary it will not work or the keys are different.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the dictionary key is not used for anything?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your three lists are all `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. In this case, it would be obvious the results could be formed easily by taking all numbers `0`...`999` *and* it would be obvious how to translate the nested `foreach` for each digit to something better: add with carry. This "add with carry" can be generalised quite easily, if for each list you create a separate enumerator and call `MoveNext()` once to point to the first element. Now, `(enumerator[0].Current, enumerator[1].Current, ...)` contains the first combination. To go to the next combination, on the last enumerator, call `MoveNext()` again. If it returns `true`, you have the next combination already. If it doesn't return `true`, reset it to point to the first element again and retry with the second-last enumerator. If at some point a `MoveNext()` returned `true`, you have the next combination. If none return `true`, you've exhausted all combinations.